# Does $f(n) = \Theta ( g(n ) )$ implies $f(n) \sim \gamma g(n)$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Saying that $f_n = \Theta(g_n)$ means there are two real constants $c_1,c_2$ and two integers $n_1,n_2$ such that

$$
c_1 g_n \leq f_n \leq c_2 g_n 
$$

for all $n \geq n_0 = \max(n_1,n_2)$, I have the feeling that because of this there's a constant $c_1 < \gamma < c_2$ such that
$$
f_n \sim \gamma g_n.
$$

You can assume also that both $g(n)$ and $f(n)$ are strictly increasing sequences and that specifically

$$
c_1 g_n < f_n < c_2 g_n 
$$

for $n \geq n_0$
My attempt to formalize was the following, for all $n$ I define the function

$$
c(\alpha)=c_1+(c_2-c_1)\alpha
$$
where $\alpha\in[0,1]$. And what I need to prove is that there's an $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that

$$
f_n \sim c(\alpha)g_n
$$

as $n$ tends to $+\infty$. This implies I have to show

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \frac{f_n}{c(\alpha)g_n}=1
$$

Or equivalently

$$
f_n = c(\alpha)g_n + o(g_n)
$$

for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$, but I don't actually know what to do... any clue? All I managed to prove is that $g_n$ can be multiplied by another sequence such that they're equivalent. But I can't prove that such sequence would converge.

Comment: Not even $f_n/g_n$ always converges, consider for example $$f_n=(6+(-1)^n)g_n$$ with $g_n\to\infty$, then indeed, $$f_n=\Theta(g_n)$$ but $f_n/g_n$ diverges since $$\liminf f_n/g_n=5\qquad \limsup f_n/g_n=7$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not.

**Counterexample 1:** Here is a counterexample for functions:
$$
g(x)=3, \qquad f(x)=3+\sin x.
$$
and similarly for sequences:
$$
g_n=3, \qquad f_n=3+(-1)^n.
$$

**Counterexample 2:** Here is a more interesting counterexample for *monotonic functions*:
$$
g(x) = 3x, \qquad f(x)=3x+x\sin \log x, \qquad x\ge1;
$$
so
$$
f'(x) = (3 x + x \sin(\log x))' = \sin \log x + \cos \log x + 3 > 0.
$$

Similarly for *monotonic sequences*:
$$
g_n = 3n, \qquad f_n=3n+n\sin \log n, \qquad n\ge1.
$$

Comment: Your $f$ is not monotonic, not strictly. Both $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be monotonic.

Comment: Added counterexample 2 for monotonic functions.

Comment: Following the same comment I made to Stella... what hypothesis could you make stronger in order to state that $\Theta$ could imply $\sim$?

Comment: That's a totally different question. Please ask a separate question, linking this one.

Comment: Done please have a look if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(n)=a^n$ for some $a$. Let $$g(n)=\begin{cases}c_1f(n)&n\text{ odd}\\c_2f(n)&n\text{ even}\end{cases}$$

For $g$ to be monotonic, you need $c_1a^n>c_2a^{n-1}$ and $c_2a^n>c_1a^{n-1}$. This means that $c_2a>c_1$ and $c_1a>c_2$, or $\frac{1}{a}<\frac{c_1}{c_2}<a.$

So, for example, we can take $a=e, c_1=1,c_2=2$.

Comment: I'm confused about what your answer mean. Can you write few words where you summarize your result?

Comment: It means that $g(n)=\Theta(f(n))$ with both monotonic, but $g(n)$ alternates between $c_1f(n)$ and $c_2f(n)$, so you can't have $g(n)\sim \lambda f(n)$ for some $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Intuition for why it's not true:

$f=\Theta(g)$ says that $f$ is never "that far" from $g$ in the sense of their ratio falling in $(c_1,c_2)$ for some $c_1,c_2$. However, this says nothing about how well behaved that ratio is, just that it falls within certain bounds. It should be obvious that there are non-convergent sequences that only take on values in $(c_1,c_2)$. Even if you require $f,g$ to be monotone, that doesn't guarantee that their ratio is monotone if they have wildly fluctuating higher-order derivatives so that $f$ gains on and falls behind $g$ (in the sense of their ratio decreasing or increasing) at an erratic rate as $x$ increases.

Comment: What kind of hypothesis could/should I make stronger to find a class of functions where $\Theta$ would imply $\sim$?

Comment: @user8469759 the key thing to realize here is that the $\Theta$ doesn't really contribute much at all to the conclusion, because it's far too weak. I would be surprised if there was a natural condition that doesn't imply the conclusion on its own, but does in conjunction with the assertion $f=\Theta(g)$