# What hypothesis could I further assume in order to say if $f_n \in \Theta(g_n)$ iff $f_n \sim \gamma g_n$ for some $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273056/does-fn-theta-gn-implies-fn-sim-gamma-gn-for-n-rightarro/2273078?noredirect=1#comment4675456_2273078) question, I was wondering what further condition could I pose in order to assure that $f(x) \in \Theta(g(x))$ iff there's a constant $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \sim \gamma g(x)$. (Please assume $x \rightarrow +\infty$).

Could some condition in the second derivative help?

Update: Please keep assuming, as the previous post the monotonicity.

Comment: One trivial condition: we must require $f_n=\gamma g_n + o(g_n)$. (Now someone will likely rephrase this into a more interesting hypothesis.)

Comment: Do you want to assume monotonic sequences/functions? Please state this explicitly.

Comment: @Alex, Yes I'll assume that.

Comment: I think no condition of the form "there is an $n$ such that $f^{(k)}$ and $g^{(k)}$ have the same sign for all $1 \leq k \leq n$" could imply the result. We could take antiderivatives of the counterexample @Alex gave in the last question to show this.

Comment: One possible interesting additional hypothesis (not quite sure if it's correct): we could require that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are monotonic  [regularly varying functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularly_varying_function), and $f_n=f(n)$, $g_n=g(n)$.

Comment: can you provide the proof? I'm not particular familiar with regularly varying functions.

Comment: @Alex sorry did you mean $f(x) \sim \gamma g(x)$?

Comment: If someone could even sketch the "proof" that would be helpful, whether or not there's a mistake I don't think that actually matters.

Answer (score 2):

On top of your original requirement that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be strictly monotonic, we need a *very* restrictive additional hypothesis.

(A) We might require that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are non-constant polynomials. Then the condition $f(x)=\Theta(g(x))$ implies that our polynomials have the same degree. Then we can take $\gamma$ to be equal to the
ratio of the leading coefficients of the two polynomials.

(B) Here is another example (also a very restrictive hypothesis):

**Theorem:** Let functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both have the form 
$C x^a \log^b x$ with positive $a,b,C$:
$$
f(x) = C_1 x^{a_1} \log^{b_1} x, \qquad g(x) = C_2 x^{a_2} \log^{b_2} x. \tag{$*$}
$$
Then
$$
f(x)=\Theta(g(x))\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad f(x)\sim \gamma g(x) \mbox{ for some } \gamma>0.
$$

*Proof*: The $\Leftarrow$ direction is trivial.

The $\Rightarrow$ direction: 
Assume that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the form $(*)$, and
$$f(x)=\Theta(g(x)). \tag{1}
$$

First we establish (by contradiction) that condition $(1)$ implies
$$a_1=a_2, \qquad b_1=b_2. \tag{2}  $$
Once we have $(2)$, choose
$$
\gamma = {C_1\over C_2}.
$$

Hypotheses (A) and (B) are somewhat too restrictive. It's probably enough to require that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ belong to a certain "nice" subset of [regularly varying functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function). (Maybe someone will develop this into another answer. Also, it might turn out that the monotonicity requirement is actually unnecessary if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ belong to a "nice" subset of regularly varying functions.)

**Note:** Requiring that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be *monotonic and regularly varying* is not enough; even *monotonic and slowly varying* is not enough! Here is a counterexample:
$$
g(x) = 3\log x, \quad f(x) = 3\log x + \log x \sin \log \log x, \quad x\ge e.
$$